# Why won't the Comprehensive Google Map Plugin load?

Tags: plugins, jquery, javascript, google-maps

all. I could use some help troubleshooting a plugin, since the plugin's author hasn't responding to support threads on the plugin page.

I'm using the [Comprehensive Google Map Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/comprehensive-google-map-plugin/) to display a map on a page. Or, at least, I'm trying to. When I put the shortcode in a page and publish it, the page gives me a loading spinner that never stops spinning.

You can see that [here](http://www.associatedkyotoprogram.dreamhosters.com/maps-and-directions-2/). (The site's still very much a work in progress, so pardon the sloppiness.)

A support thread in the WordPress plugin repository from three weeks ago for a similar issue (I'd post a link, but I haven't got enough reputation yet) suggests that the problem might be an HTML error causing a Javascript error, but I'm not sure how to find an error like that, if that's even my issue.

If anyone could take a look and suggest solutions, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks so much.

Comment: Google maps has some pretty robust copy/paste options (zoom, map type, markers, etc), have you looked at just adding one manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the JavaScript error console, you'll see the plugin is throwing an error:

```
Error: SyntaxError: missing ) after condition
Source File: http://www.associatedkyotoprogram.dreamhosters.com/wp-content/plugins/comprehensive-google-map-plugin/assets/js/cgmp.framework.min.js?ver=7.0.31
Line: 33, Column: 60
Source Code:
tions").val();d=w(d);m=parseFloat(a.fn.jquery);if(1.3>m && m~=1.10)return alert(i.oldJquery),!1;if("undefined"==
```

If you look at the plugin page, you'll that the majority of people are reporting the plugin as broken, and it hasn't been updated for almost a year.

It's time to find an alternative plugin.